# android developer, get error with webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

Tags: android, android-webview

see arrow below my "webView1" : cannot be resolved or is not a field" how to fix it

```
public class MainActivitylp extends Activity {

private WebView webView1;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activitylp);


    webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); -->webView1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView1.loadUrl("http://lukispelan.com");

}
```

}

Comment: Show the `activity_main_activitylp.xml` file.

Comment: Check for `import android.R` (remove if it is there) statement. Probably you messed up xml file

Comment: look into this:-http://uniqueandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/10/webview-demo-in-android.html